# 'File' object has no attribute 'select'

Tags: python, pandas, csv, attributes, hdf5

I am currently trying to run a program that is supposed to read an .HDF5 file and rewrite the components into a csv file:

```
import h5py as hdf
import pandas as pd

#df = pd.read_hdf('ne2011216lf.hdf5')

#Specify file
FILE_NAME = 'ne2011216lf.hdf5'

file = hdf.File(FILE_NAME, 'r')

#.select(n) will let you select the nth parameter stored in the file

dat_times = file.select(0).get()
dat_heights = file.select(1).get()
dat_den = file.select(2).get()

dsize = dat_den.shape
tsize = dat_times.shape
htsize = dat_heights.shape

# dat_times

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(dat_den, columns = dat_times, index = dat_heights)

df.to_csv('ne2011216lf.hdf5')
```

Running this code displays an error message on the 13th line saying:
"Attribute Error: 'File' object has no attribute 'select'"

I have no idea how to fix this. can anyone help?

Comment: use `print(dir(file))` to see available attributes.

Comment: hdf.File not having select attribute due to this you are getting this error.

Comment: any clue as to what attribute I should use to get the nth parameter stored in the file? (i.e. the comment on line 11 is wrong, which attribute should I use in place of select since select does not exist)